# What is the recommended way to pass data back and forth between two threads using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an app that will pass data between two servers Connection1 and Conenction2 using sockets.What i would like to do is receive data from Connection1 and pass it to Connection2 and vice-versa.Connection1 and Conenction2 are on different threads. What is the best way to call methods on different threads in order to pass data back and forth between them.Both threads will use the same message object type to communicate in both directions between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use immutable data transfer objects.

As long as a simple object is deeply immutable (meaning that neither it nor any of it's properties can change), there is nothing wrong with using it on multiple threads.

To pass the instances between threads, you might want to use a [pseudo-mutable thread-safe stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx).  (This depends on your design)

Answer (score 2):

If .NET 4 is an option, I'd strongly recommend having a look at the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(VS.100).aspx) and possibly even wrapping it with a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(VS.100).aspx) if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what those threads are doing. While passing data between threads is relatively straight forward, waking the threads to process the data can be more tricky. When you design communication with a thread per/connection paradigm, your thread is almost all the time stuck in a Read method, like [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). While in this state, other threads cannot actually wake this thread to have him send the data they want it sent. One solution is to have the Receive time out every second and check if it has data to transmit, but that just plain sucks.

Another idea is to have 2 threads per socket, one to Send one to Receive. But then all the advantages of having a thread per socket are gone: you are no longer able to have a simple state management of the 'session' in the thread code, you have a state shared between two threads and it's just a mess.

You can consider using async Receive instead: the socket thread posts a [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) then waits on an event. The event is signaled by either the Receive completion *or* by the send queue having something 'dropped' in (or you can wait on multiple events, same thing basically). Now this would work, but at this moment you have a half-breed, part async part one-thread -per-socket. If you go down this path, I'd go the whole 9 yards: make the server fully async.

Going fully async would be the best solution. Instead of exchanging data between threads, completion routines operate on locked data. The Connection1 BeginReceive completes when it receives data, you parse the received data and analyze the content, then decide to send it on Connection2. So you invoke BeginSend on Connection2's socket, meaning the *thread that received the data also send the data*. This is much more efficient ans scales better than the thread-per-socket model, but the big disadvantage is that is just plain complicated if you're mot familiar with async and multithreaded programming.

See [Asynchronous Server Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx) and [Asynchronous Client Socket Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) for a primer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing as asynchronous messaging. Microsoft has already written an app for this called [MSMQ](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx)

Answer (score -2):

I would use WCF on .NET 3.5 for this task, it will be more scalable. I'm using WCF for a lot of my works and its flawless. The good thing about it is you can share your data across any platform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx